# Application ENDING time AND STARTING time

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

I am newbie to the Qt framework,
I have to develop an App  in My project, I need to develop an App on symbian It about to Track the Application STARTING time and ENDING time  in the mobile..

Could any one please share information how to do this task..

thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QDateTime::currentDateTime()` to get the time ([QDateTime](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatetime.html#currentDateTime)) and then from there you can store however you fancy, I'd assume from your question tags it'll be in an SQLite database so you'd just use one of the standard `QSqlQuery` methods to do it. On start just add it in as the application is loading in `main()` and on end you can track the `quit()` signal and go from there.

Comment: Thanks sir, and is there  any use with QTimers to write this code

Comment: Not really, you can use them but they're a bit redundant as I'm guessing you want the time as it starts (which is in main) and when it's ending (which is when the quit signal is emitted), adding QTimers on would just allow you to trap the time at the end of the timer.

Comment: Sir, how to get output data without using Sqlite(&sql queries), My colleague told me that No need to Append Sqlite  in this task,